# Failed to resolve: com.android.support:renderscript

Tags: android, android-studio, compiler-errors

*All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 25.3.1, 25.0.2, 25.0.0, 23.4.0. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.3.1 and com.android.support:renderscript:25.0.2*

I always solved this issue by adding reported libraries. But this is not working for this library. I added following library without any problem:

***compile com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.3.1***

But I can´t do same for following library:

***compile com.android.support:renderscript:25.0.2***

When I add this, it shows following error:

***Failed to resolve: com.android.support:renderscript:25.0.2***